# Let $b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c \ge b$ and for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $a > b \implies a \ge c$. Then $b=c$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c \ge b$ and for all $a  \in \mathbb{R}$, $a > b \implies a \ge c$. Then $b=c$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct claim seems to be this:

> Let $b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $c \ge b$ and for all $a  \in \mathbb{R}$, $a > b \implies a \ge c$. Then $b=c$.

To prove this, suppose $c > b$ and consider any $a$ strictly between $b$ and $c$.